# Find closed form formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I need help to find closed form formula for this summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(x-y)^i$$

Comment: use the geometric series with $r=(x-y)$

Comment: Do you know the closed form for $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$?

Comment: @aschepler, no, could you please let me know, what is it?

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), which has sum $$\frac{1}{1-(x-y)},$$

provided it converges at all.  It will converge precisely when $|x-y|<1$, and diverge otherwise.